# .NET WCF Service Consume JSON/XML Push

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf

I would like to Consume a JSON Push from Shopify with my WCF Service. What would be the best way to go about this?

I have a hosted WCF Service that communicates with my Local Applications. I would like to consume a Shopify JSON/XML Push, interpenetrate the data and notify my application.

Shopify Webhooks - 
You can subscribe to events for your products and orders by creating web hooks that will push XML or JSON notifications to a given URL.

Comment: You mean a WCF service?

Comment: I have edited your question. You're mistaking WPF with WCF.